# Droid X Flashlight doesn't turn on the same way as other phones?

Tags: android

I've been developing and app to turn on the LED light next the camera on Android. I have my code working for the Incredible and the Charge (because they are the only two other devices I have to test on) but I can't seem to get the Droid X LED to turn on. Is there some other way to turn on the camera's flashlight programmatically? I am also pretty sure all my permissions are correct considering it does work on other phones.

Here is the basic code being used to turn it on.

```
cam = Camera.open();
params = cam.getParameters();
params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(params);
cam.startPreview();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just set any flash mode you want because a camera driver may not support it. You need to get available flash modes using `Parameters.getSupportedFlashModes()`, check whether the mode you want to set is supported or not and set it if it's supported. So I assume it's not supported on Droid X.

Comment: The supported flash modes for the Charge are (Auto, On , Off). The supported flash modes for the Droid X are (On, Off, Auto, Torch). Both I had printed out by the getSupportedFlashMode() function.

Comment: In order to use non-auto flash mode the scene mode must be set to `SCENE_MODE_AUTO`. Also you should check what value is returned from `getFlashMode()` after you set camera parameters.

Comment: I've tried doing both of these. The return I get when I set it to TORCH mode is that it is in torch mode but no LED comes on.....

Comment: I think it's a problem of this particular device.